# LocalBridge of degree k in Graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

What would be the best algorithm to find localbridge(k) in Graph? A local bridge of degree k is an edge whose removal would enlarge the shortest distance between its two end-points to at least k.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(interpersonal)#Local_bridge

Comment: Is [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) good enough?

Comment: Are you interested in finding all local bridges in the graph?  Perhaps you had one (or two) specific nodes in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run an all-shortest-path-costs algorithm, like the **Floyd-Warshall algorithm**, but where you use tuples `(d1,d2)` for distances, instead of the typical real numbers `d`:

- `d1` is the length of the shortest path
- `d2` is the length of the ***second*** shortest path

This modification to the Floyd-Warshall algorithm should be straightforward.

When you are done running the all-shortest-path-costs algorithm, the `localbridge(k)` edges are those edges `e = {u, v}` such that the distance `(1,d2)` between `u` and `v` satisfies `d2 >= k`.